# Populating multiple dependent spinners via string resource

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

As a struggling newbie I've set up 3 spinners that pull string arrays depending on what item is selected. It is a Year, Make, and Model setup for sorting through vehicles that will pull information from a sqlite3 database depending on the vehicle selected. So Year is a basic spinner (2000 through 2019). However the next spinner, Make, populates depending on the year selected. More over, the Model spinner depends on what Make is selected. I have approx. 80 string arrays for Models that are only available during certain years. With all that said, I've puzzle-pieced this frankenstein monster code together from research. The only solution that I could think of would be about 100 if statements to make these spinners populate with all the options. Below is the code that has been cut down to prevent wasting space when repetition occurs. *ANY criticism, help, or ideas are greatly appreciated.*

**MainActivity.java**

```
 import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
                                                                    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        private  DrawerLayout drawer;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            spinStrYear = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.year);
            spinStrMake = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.make);
            spinStrModel = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.model);
            spinYear = findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear);
            spinMake = findViewById(R.id.spinnerMake);
            spinModel = findViewById(R.id.spinnerModel);

            ar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinStrYear);
            ar2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinStrMake);
            ar3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinStrModel);
            spinYear.setAdapter(ar);
            spinMake.setAdapter(ar2);
            spinModel.setAdapter(ar3);

            spinYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

                if (spinYear.getSelectedItem().equals("2000"))
                    ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinMake.setAdapter(ar2);
            }


                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

            spinMake.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
if (spinMake.getSelectedItem().equals("Acura")) {
                    ar2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinModel.setAdapter(ar3);
                }

                if (spinMake.getSelectedItem().equals("Audi")) {

                }

                if (spinMake.getSelectedItem().equals("BMW"))  {

                }

                if (spinMake.getSelectedItem().equals("Cadillac"))  {

                }
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="year">   // Year spinner population
        <item>2000</item>
        <item>2001</item>
        <item>2002</item>
        <item>2003</item>
        <item>2004</item>
        <item>2005</item>
        <item>2006</item>
        <item>2007</item>
        <item>2008</item>
        <item>2009</item>
        <item>2010</item>
        <item>2011</item>
        <item>2012</item>
        <item>2013</item>
        <item>2014</item>
        <item>2015</item>
        <item>2016</item>
        <item>2017</item>
        <item>2018</item>
        <item>2019</item>
    </string-array>                 // End of year spinner population

    <string-array name="make">       // Make spinner population
    <item>Acura</item>
    <item>Audi</item>
    <item>BMW</item>
    <item>Buick</item>
    <item>Cadillac</item>
    </string-array>                     // End of Make spinner population


    <string-array name="Acura2000">       // Model spinner population
        <item>Integra</item>
        <item>NSX</item>
        <item>RL</item>
        <item>TL</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Acura2001">
        <item>CL</item>
        <item>Integra</item>
        <item>MDX</item>
        <item>NSX</item>
        <item>RL</item>
        <item>TL</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Acura2002_03"> // Same data for 02 and 03
        <item>CL</item>
        <item>MDX</item>
        <item>NSX</item>
        <item>RL</item>
        <item>RSX</item>
        <item>TL</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Acura2004_05"> // Same data for 04 and 05
        <item>MDX</item>
        <item>NSX</item>
        <item>RL</item>
        <item>RSX</item>
        <item>TL</item>
        <item>TSX</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Acura2006">
    <item>MDX</item>
    <item>RL</item>
    <item>RSX</item>
    <item>TL</item>
    <item>TSX</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making string arrays for every **Make** in every **Year**. I re-arrange to have **Make** and **Model** with their production period, then generate the lists at run-time. Try the following:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner spinYear, spinMake, spinModel;
ArrayAdapter ar, ar2, ar3;
String[] spinStrYear;
ArrayList<String> spinStrMake, spinStrModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinYear = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinMake = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinModel = findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    spinStrYear = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.year);
    spinStrMake = new ArrayList<>();
    spinStrModel = new ArrayList<>();

    ar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinStrYear);
    ar2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinStrMake);
    ar3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinStrModel);
    spinYear.setAdapter(ar);
    spinMake.setAdapter(ar2);
    spinModel.setAdapter(ar3);

    spinYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            updateSpinnerMake();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
    spinMake.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            updateSpinnerModel(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
}

private void updateSpinnerMake() {
    int selectedYear = Integer.parseInt(spinYear.getSelectedItem().toString());
    spinStrMake.clear();
    String[] tmpMakeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.make);
    for (String tmpMake : tmpMakeArray) {
        String[] tmpMakeDetails = getResources().getStringArray(getResources().getIdentifier(
                tmpMake, "array", getPackageName()));
        int startYear = Integer.parseInt(tmpMakeDetails[0]);
        int stopYear = Integer.parseInt(tmpMakeDetails[1]);
        if (selectedYear >= startYear && selectedYear <= stopYear) spinStrMake.add(tmpMake);
    }
    if (spinStrMake.size() == 0) spinStrMake.add("No make on that year!!");
    ar2.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (spinMake.getSelectedItemPosition() >= 0) updateSpinnerModel(spinMake.getSelectedItemPosition());
    else updateSpinnerModel(0);
}

private void updateSpinnerModel(int position) {
    spinStrModel.clear();
    if (!spinStrMake.get(0).equals("No make on that year!!")){
        int selectedYear = Integer.parseInt(spinYear.getSelectedItem().toString());
        String[] tmpModelArray = getResources().getStringArray(getResources().getIdentifier(
                spinStrMake.get(position), "array", getPackageName()));
        String tmpModel;
        for (int j=2; j<tmpModelArray.length; j++) {
            tmpModel = tmpModelArray[j];
            String[] period = getResources().getStringArray(getResources().getIdentifier(
                    tmpModel, "array", getPackageName()));
            int startYear = Integer.parseInt(period[0]);
            int stopYear = Integer.parseInt(period[1]);
            if (selectedYear >= startYear && selectedYear <= stopYear)
                spinStrModel.add(tmpModel);
        }
        if (spinStrModel.size() == 0) spinStrModel.add("No Match Model Found!!");
    }
    ar3.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

strings.xml:

```
    <string-array name="year">// Year spinner population
    <item>2000</item>
    <item>2001</item>
    <item>2002</item>
    <item>2003</item>
    <item>2004</item>
    <item>2005</item>
    <item>2006</item>
    <item>2007</item>
    <item>2008</item>
    <item>2009</item>
    <item>2010</item>
    <item>2011</item>
    <item>2012</item>
    <item>2013</item>
    <item>2014</item>
    <item>2015</item>
    <item>2016</item>
    <item>2017</item>
    <item>2018</item>
    <item>2019</item>
</string-array>// End of year spinner population

<string-array name="make">// Make spinner population
    <item>Acura</item>
    <item>Audi</item>
</string-array>// End of Make spinner population

<string-array name="Acura">
    <item>2000</item>
    <item>2006</item>
    <item>CL</item>// All Models grouped under Acura should be here
    <item>Integra</item>
    <item>MDX</item>
    <item>NSX</item>
    <item>RL</item>
    <item>RSX</item>
    <item>TL</item>
    <item>TSX</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="CL">
    <item>2001</item>
    <item>2003</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Integra">
    <item>2000</item>
    <item>2001</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="MDX">
    <item>2001</item>
    <item>2006</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="NSX">
    <item>2000</item>
    <item>2005</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="RL">
    <item>2000</item>
    <item>2006</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="RSX">
    <item>2002</item>
    <item>2006</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="TL">
    <item>2000</item>
    <item>2006</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="TSX">
    <item>2004</item>
    <item>2006</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Audi">
    <item>2001</item>
    <item>2007</item>
    <item>Audi1</item>
    <item>Audi2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Audi1">
    <item>2001</item>
    <item>2006</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Audi2">
    <item>2004</item>
    <item>2007</item>
</string-array>
```

Hope that helps!